# jQuery target anchor tags inside unactive tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, tags, anchor

I am working on a restaurant deliver website and am trying to figure out how I can target anchor tags that are inside a tab from other tabs, for example, the main tabs would be: Menu, Info, Reviews, but then inside the menu tab I want to have a submenu that lists food types (Appetizers, entrees, ect...) Ideally I'd like them to all be visible at once and if for instance you clicked from Reviews to Desserts you would go into the Menu tab to the dessert anchor.

```
<ul class='tabs'>
<li><a href='#tab1'>Menu</a></li>
    <ul class="submenu">
       <?php foreach ($contents as $header_id => $item_array): ?>
       <li>
          <a href="#<?php echo $item_array[0]["content"] ?>"><?php echo $item_array[0]["content"] ?></a>
       </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<li><a href='#tab2'>Info</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab3'>Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I target anchor tags that are inside a tab from other tabs?

Try using the `find()` method, which "*Gets the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.*"

```
$('ul.tabs li ul.submenu').each(function() {
    var anchors = $(this).find('a'); //these anchors are per sub menu.
});
```

Comment: So from here, how would I write "if submenu item is clicked; open menu tab and go to anchor" Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To switch from one tab to another by clicking a link, you probably need to attach custom handlers to those links.

For example:

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" class="desertLink">Dessert</a></li>
```

JS:

```
$(".desertLink").click(function(){
  $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
  $( "html, body" ).animate({scrollTop:$('#dessert_id').position().top}, 'slow');
});
```

would switch your tab from the Menu tab to the Info tab.

For more options, take a look at the Tabs API at http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Comment: I can navigate between the top level tabs, what I am trying to figure out is how I can go from a tab like "Info" to an anchor tag in the Menu div. For instance, from the Info tab, click "Desserts" which would open the menu tab and go to the Dessert anchor tag.

Comment: You can use `scrollTop` once you switched the tabs... I updated my answer to show an example.